# v-model weird behavior or it's normal in VueJS

Tags: vue.js

I saw an weird behavior in v-model but i don't know what should i call it. is it normal or weird.

HTML Markup:

```
<div id="app">
 <div>EditItem: {{ editItem }}</div>
 <div>FormData: {{ formData }}</div>
 <input type="text" v-model="formData.name" label="name" />
</div>
```

Script:

```
new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 data: {
   editItem: { name: 'Mr. Coder' },
   formData: null,
 },
 created() {
   this.formData = this.editItem
 },
```

So my question is when I change the input value of `formData` using v-model it is also change the `editItem` value. but why? I have already attached the value of `formData` using `created` method. So it should change the `formData` only. Can anyone explain me about this behavior in detail or is there any way that it doesn't change the `editItem` value but can change only `formData` using v-model? Thanks.

For your reference see the JSFiddle URL: https://jsfiddle.net/nhxjp8m1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a Vue specific behaviour but rather a JavaScript one. When you wrote

```
this.formData = this.editItem
```

It did not create a copy of editItem but rather formData now REFERS to editItem. Therefore changing formData directly changes editItem and vice-versa.

I believe the behaviour you seeks requires copying editItem into formData using `Object.assign()`.

For more information about JavaScript, I suggest going through this [website](https://javascript.info/js).

Comment: @CoderByte71 you can upvote the answer and accept in order to thank the respondent

Answer (score 0):

Well `editItem` is a non-primitive type. If you assign some other variable with your non primitive type you copy the reference to it rather then the value itself.

You did a [pass by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104494/does-javascript-pass-by-reference)

You could use the spread operator to make a copy of it without an reference:

```
 created() {
   this.formData = { ...this.editItem }
 },
```

Comment: Yeah, I have learned it now. This article helps me a lot. Here is the article -https://javascript.info/object-copy